# Stripe payment integration in controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

How would you do for that action would execute if the stripe payment is performing

My action controller:

```
def create
    @action = Action.new(action_params)
    @action.user = current_user
    if @action.save
         redirect_to new_charge_path
    else
        render :new
    end
end
```

I would like my @ action.save is executed only if the payment
is done.

(new_charge_path is stripe route)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want specific action to be called when a user makes a payment. If that's what you want, you need to setup [stripe webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks).

Stripe servers will make a HTTP request to URL specified by you with all payment details. Give stripe your route to your `create` action.